# RabbitMQ does not start

Tags: installation, rabbitmq

I installed rabbitmq on my local environment but it asks me to install erlang, so I did. Once the two installations are finished I launch rabbitMQ but I receive an error. I check the port to use for rabbitmq and I see that there is already a service running on this port and it is erlang, I write a new configuration file rabbitmq.conf but to specify the port to use but it does not work. Can someone help me ?

Here is the error:

> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.11.15\sbin>rabbitmq-server start                                                                                                                                                          2023-05-02 12:02:05.052000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0> You've tried to set listeners.tcp.10.0.0.1, but there is no setting with that name.                                                                                                       2023-05-02 12:02:05.083000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>   Did you mean one of these?                                                                                                                                                              2023-05-02 12:02:05.249000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     listeners.tcp.$name                                                                                                                                                                   2023-05-02 12:02:05.249000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     listeners.tcp                                                                                                                                                                         2023-05-02 12:02:05.249000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     listeners.ssl.$name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                2023-05-02 12:02:05.249000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0> Error preparing configuration in phase transform_datatypes:                                                                                                                               BOOT FAILED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2023-05-02 12:02:05.249000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>   - Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: listeners.tcp.10.0.0.1                                                                                                                   ===========                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  2023-05-02 12:02:05.256000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                                                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:05.256000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0> BOOT FAILED                                                                                                                                                                               2023-05-02 12:02:05.256000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0> ===========                                                                                                                                                                               2023-05-02 12:02:05.256000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0> Error during startup: {error,failed_to_prepare_configuration}                                                                                                                             2023-05-02 12:02:05.256000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                                                                                                                                                                                           Error during startup: {error,failed_to_prepare_configuration}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     supervisor: {local,rabbit_prelaunch_sup}                                                                                                                                              2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     errorContext: start_error                                                                                                                                                             2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     reason: failed_to_prepare_configuration                                                                                                                                               2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>     offender: [{pid,undefined},                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {id,prelaunch},                                                                                                                                                            2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {mfargs,{rabbit_prelaunch,run_prelaunch_first_phase,[]}},                                                                                                                  2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {restart_type,transient},                                                                                                                                                  2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {significant,false},                                                                                                                                                       2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {shutdown,5000},                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                {child_type,worker}]                                                                                                                                                       2023-05-02 12:02:06.285000+02:00 [error] <0.131.0>                                                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>   crasher:                                                                                                                                                                                2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     initial call: application_master:init/4                                                                                                                                               2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     pid: <0.129.0>                                                                                                                                                                        2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     registered_name: []                                                                                                                                                                   2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     exception exit: {{shutdown,                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>                          {failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,                                                                                                                                2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>                              failed_to_prepare_configuration}},                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>                      {rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}                                                                                                                            2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>       in function  application_master:init/4 (application_master.erl, line 142)                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     ancestors: [<0.128.0>]                                                                                                                                                                2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     message_queue_len: 1                                                                                                                                                                  2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     messages: [{'EXIT',<0.130.0>,normal}]                                                                                                                                                 2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     links: [<0.128.0>,<0.44.0>]                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     dictionary: []                                                                                                                                                                        2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     trap_exit: true                                                                                                                                                                       2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     status: running                                                                                                                                                                       2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     heap_size: 233                                                                                                                                                                        2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     stack_size: 28                                                                                                                                                                        2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>     reductions: 170                                                                                                                                                                       2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>   neighbours:                                                                                                                                                                             2023-05-02 12:02:06.287000+02:00 [error] <0.129.0>                                                                                                                                                                                           2023-05-02 12:02:06.321000+02:00 [notice] <0.44.0> Application rabbitmq_prelaunch exited with reason: {{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_prepare_configuration}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}                {"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_prepare_configuration}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}                    Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,rabbitmq_prelaunch,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,prelaunch,failed_to_prepare_configuration}},{rabbit_prelaunch_app,start,[normal,[]]}}})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was finally able to get the configurations accepted in my rabbitmq.conf file. but I can't access the rabbitmq GUI

`listeners.tcp.external = 0.0.0.0:5672
listeners.tcp.internal = 127.0.0.1:5672
listeners.ssl.default = 5671`

Comment: The gui listens on port 15672

Comment: Thanks Pablo, i already solve the issue. I activated the GUI in command line.